# Problem with fscanf function while using *char

Tags: c++

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "w+");
    char *tab;
    char *tab2;
    cout << "Input: " << endl;
    cin >> tab;
    fprintf(file, "%s", tab);
    rewind(file);
    fscanf(file, "%s", tab2);
    printf("%s", tab2);
    fclose(file);
}
```

So saving to file is working, but while I want to read from `file` to `*tab2` it doesn't work and program instantly crashes. Any help with this?

Comment: You are operating on uninitialized pointers, that's _undefined behavior_.

Comment: It's frankly a miracle the first half works. `tab` and `tab2` point to, erm, whatever they feel like pointing to. Could be valid memory, could be NULL, could be your operating system. See [Undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

```
char *tab;
char *tab2;
```

These lines just declare pointers to unspecified addresses. When you try reading or writing through those pointers, you are invoking *undefined behavior*. You might get a crash, or you might not.  Or you might just corrupt memory.

You need to allocate memory buffers and then make those pointers point to those buffers.  But, because you are using C++, not just plain C, just use C++ ways of working with strings, reading files, etc. There are `std::string` and `std::ifstream` classes for this purpose.